# Using a .txt list as argument for my first script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, text-files

I'm using a program named `gallery-DL`, which allows me to scrape pictures from various websites. Right now I'm launching it in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) manually, but I'd like to write a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to launch the scraping of different urls one after the other.

The command in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) so far is

```
Gallery-DL.exe "URL"
```

I'd like to write a script were I could simply update a [text-file](/questions/tagged/text-file) with the URLs in columns to be used one after the other.

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do gallery-dl.exe "%%a"`

Comment: Just to clarify, due to your use of the term columns, the above comment, expects that your text file contains only one URL per line.

Comment: It is the case, only one URL per line for simplicity, thank you for the answer and clarification !

Answer (score 0):

You can write this several ways.

The following will let you drag a txt file with urls in it onto the batch script to run, or allow you to type the path in the cli after the name of the batch script.

```
@(Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  Echo off
  SET "_Args=%*"
  SET "_Args=!_Args:"=!"
  SET "_CMD=C:\Path\To\Gallery-DL.exe"
)
CALL :Main
( Endlocal
  Exit/b )

:Main
  ECHO=
  If Defined _Args (
    If Exist "%_Args%" (
      For %%_ in ("%_Args%") DO (
        "%_CMD%" "%~_%" )
    ) ELSE (
      ECHO=File does not exist!
      ECHO= The path provided was: "%_Args%"
  ) Else (
    ECHO=No Arguments provided to command!
    ECHO= Please provide a path to a file with URLs as an argument!
  )
  Echo=
  Echo=Script Completed
Goto :EOF
```

Took a while to write this having a mini crisis with car.  Loops like Stephen answered similarly in comments in the mean time

Comment: I surely did. :)  Thanks @Stephan